# How do you translate the following code to Intel Assembly code (x86)?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel

I'm trying to translate to x86 assembly to help me get a better understanding of the concept on coding in x86 assembly and I'm feeling stuck on how to even start on this code.

```
int temp = 0;
int acc = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    temp = temp + i;
    if (temp > 5)
    {
           acc = acc * temp;
    }
}
printf(“Answer is %d\n", acc);
```

Comment: Compile with gcc -S and take a look at the generated code, http://godbolt,org is useful for this,

Comment: Aside: `acc` remains firmly `0` since multiplying anything by `0` is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an IDE like Visual Studio, you can target an x86 platform and view assembly using the [Disassembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-disassembly-window?view=vs-2019) window.

Keep in mind that flags will change the generated assembly, so I would make sure to adjust optimizations accordingly.

Comment: Usually you want some optimization if you're going to read the asm for a small simple loop.  For something larger and complex, it can turn into a big mess, but for small stuff optimization mostly removes noise, especially if you only enable `gcc -Og` minimal optimization.  It helps to write a function that takes args, otherwise constant-propagation will compute more stuff at compile time. e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/r6ofzP

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I edited my answer accordingly.